# WiX: Define a File component that may not exist

Tags: wix, wix3

I need to define a Wix file component that may not exist in certain circumstances. Is there any way to do this? Condition elements in Wix all seem to work at install time, and I need something that'll detect at compile time if a file is present and build the installer accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As iwo said, [preprocessor variables](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/preprocessor.htm) are your friend! However the example from iwo can (and will) violate component rules, as the component isn't 'stable'. Better to condition an entire component (or component group)...

```
<?if $(var.releasetype)=full ?>
  <ComponentRef Id="Somefile.dll" />
<?elseif  $(var.releasetype)=enterprise ?>
  <ComponentGroupRef Id="SomethingElse" />
<?endif?>
```

And then include the `Component` and `ComponentGroup`s in separate `Fragment` tags so that they will only be compiled when referenced :)

```
<Fragment>
  <Component Id="Somefile.dll" Guid="*">
    <File Id="Somefile.dll" KeyPath="yes" Source="SourceDir\Somefile.dll" />
  </Component>
</Fragment>

<Fragment>
  <ComponentGroup Id="SomethingElse">
    <ComponentRef Id="Somefile.dll" />
    <Component Id="AnotherFile.dll>
      <File Id="AnotherFile.dll" KeyPath="yes" Source="SourceDir\AnotherFile.dll" />
    </Component>
  </ComponentGroup>
</Fragment>
```

Personally I use [nant](http://nant.sourceforge.net/) to call `candle` and `light` targets, defining different variables for various different builds and products, effective use of fragments and preprocessor variables provides a great opportunity for code re-use between projects, or various releases of the same project.

In your case, to check if a file exists... then you'd just use the internal functions to define, or redefine a variable that is later passed to WiX. e.g.:

```
<if test="${not file::exists('something.dll')}">
    <property name="releasetype" value="blahblahblah" />
</if>
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems you need to check out the wix preprocessor. Check out wix documentation on the topic:
[wix preprocessor](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/preprocessor.htm)

for example, suppose you have an environment variable called APPTYPE. If its value is set to 'Full', then MyApp_Full.exe will be included and processed by the wix compiler (candle).

```
<Component Id='MyComponent1' Guid='fff60f72-5553-4e6b-9bf0-ad62ab9a90b1'>
 <?if $(env.APPTYPE) = Full?>
   <File Name='MyApp_Full.exe' DiskId='1' Source='..\MyApp_Full.exe' Vital='yes' />
 <?endif?>
 ...
</Component>
```

There is more! Variables, defines, conditionals. Check out that doc page.